# How to hire junior developers under me and convince clients to let them work on project

Tags: subcontracting

I am an experienced developer and I get enough work for my self. I get more work then I can handle my self. So I am planning to hire junior developers under me, start an agency and assign work to them. Now the question is, most of the clients would want me only to work on the project. How to approach clients and convince them that it's okay to let my junior developers work and I will keep eye on their quality of code and ensure that they deliver as promised, and i would charge less for the junior developers.

Comment: You approach clients with exactly the story you just wrote down here: Lots of work, extra help, junior so lower fee but you monitor quality. Client get more done, and pays equal or maybe even less.

Answer (score 2):

Agency is like a company right? Would you monitor juniors? If yes, then you have better chance of clients trusting you.

Firstly, be open with clients. Secondly, do offer lower price. Don't expect that juniors can work for the price of a senior. Lastly, DO monitor their work as they work under your name.

Be prepared that juniors will leave you and that you will have to finalize the project yourself. So always spare some time for monitoring which you can use for finalizing project if things go wrong.

Also, be prepared that you will have to do hard parts of the projects as juniors are either not capable or will do it wrongly.

Comment: except now he's also wearing a "project management" hat - should there not be compensation for that?

Comment: Yes, he can take any percentage or flat fee for that.

Answer (score 0):

Put yourself in client's position. Think why they have been giving work to you? Was it their past experience with you, referral, your good school etc.? Then keeping yourself in client's position, think if your contractor wants to employ junior developers, what would be your reaction. For example, any precondition and guarantee and formal quality metrics would you want?